# Iterating through array and await dealing with promises

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I am creating a todo application and I would like each todo list to have a unique name. Each user has an array of todo lists. An incoming POST request to create a new list has the user object attached to it so I can get the array using `const userLists = req.user.list`. This (if I console log it) is each list `_id`.

I am trying to loop through these to get the list object and test the name to see if it equals `req.body.name` to ensure uniqueness.

I would prefer to keep the function `async` as I have more logic below and would prefer not to nest too many callback functions.

I have tried

```
exports.createList = async (req, res) => {
const usersLists = req.user.lists;
  let proms = [];
  let found = false;
userLists.map(list => {
const listObj = List.findOne({_id : list});
if(listObj.name === req.body.name)
   found = true
})
(other code below to create list)
```

and also tried to `await List.findOne()` but i can't `async` the map.

I believe the code is running past this and so `found` is never true.

I then saw something online that used `Promise.all()` and so i tried this:

```
let proms = []
usersLists.map(listId => {
    proms.push(List.findOne({_id: listId}, "name").exec());
  });
await Promise.all(proms.map(p => {
  if(p.name == req.body.name)
    found = true;
}))
```

but the code below still runs and the list is created. If i `console.log(proms)` then it consists of an array of [object Promise].

It is still fairly new to me and all I am trying to do is loop through an Array of List id's, get the list object and test to see if any of the list names is equal to the name of the new list I want to create (and return an error)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It should be `const listObjs = await Promise.all(proms);`. Then you can loop through `listObjs`.

Comment: Fantastic. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the responses, even if they are valid, they tend to change external variables within an async operation, that is exacly what you shouldn't do, never.

Theoretically it should be reduced to something like (not tested):

```js
const promises = usersLists.map(listId => List.findOne({_id: listId}, "name"));

const isFound = await Promise.all(promises).then(arr => {
//check your array
// return true or false
});

console.log("Result...", isFound);
```

By the way... you can always query mongo without executing a bunch of findOne. Normally you can make it in a single call or at least group it in fewer calls.

Answer (score 1):

let me break down the problem here

```
let proms = []
usersLists.map(listId => {
    proms.push(List.findOne({_id: listId}, "name").exec());
  });
await Promise.all(proms.map(p => {
  if(p.name == req.body.name)
    found = true;
}))
```

Firstly,

```
let proms = []
usersLists.map(
```

Will return a new array so you don't need to have `let proms = []` and push to it.
And also you can use `async/await` inside the map callback.
What you can do instead is

```
const promises = usersLists.map(async listId => {
    const prom = await List.findOne({_id: listId}, "name").exec();
    if(p.name == req.body.name) // I put this here so we don't have to make another loop
        found = true;
});
```

When the map loop is finished `promises` will be an array of promises. So to make javascript await all of those promises you will now use `Promise.all(promises)`.
And to do that, here is how

```
await Promise.all(promises);
```

---

And here you go, the final output

```
const promises = usersLists.map(async listId => {
    const prom = await List.findOne({_id: listId}, "name").exec();
    if(p.name == req.body.name)
        found = true;
});
await Promise.all(promises);
```

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly. One thing I must be missing, if we `await` when finding one. Why do we still need to `Promise.all()`

Comment: Additionally... Doing "found = true" is a very bad practice, it's error prone and very race condition friendly. Promise.all returns an array of fulfilled responses, you can simply use "then" on that array and use functions like "some" to find what you need.
Declaring externally variables that are changed within promises is something to avoid.

Comment: It's because `usersLists.map(` does not iterate synchronously. Each iteration will be processed concurrently. `await` only works in the `async` function it was used, the outer function will not wait for the `await`s of the inner function.

Comment: Thanks folks, I'll try and remove the found = true stuff.

Comment: You don't need to await inside map, you can simply map promises execute a Promise.all on that. The other check can be done just after, something like ```const found = await Promise.all(....).then(...your function that returns true or false...)```

Answer (score 0):

`Promise.all` accepts an array that contains promises and resolves when all of them are done.Please read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Assuming above code is executed in an `async` function

```
 let found = false;  
let proms = usersLists.map(listId => List.findOne({
      _id: listId
    }, "name").exec());
    let userDetails = await Promise.all(proms);

    for (let index = 0; index < userDetails.length; index++) {
      const user = userDetails[index]
      if (user.name === req.body.name) {
        found = true
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

as i see, try this?

```
let found = false
// proms:users all message in List model
let proms = await Promise.all(
     // usersLists: user id message ['', '']
     usersLists.map(async listId => {
         // List: user model, listObj {_id: '', name: ''}
         const listObj = await List.findOne({_id : listId});
         if(listObj.name == req.body.name){
             found = true
         }
         return listObj
     });
)
// other code
```